# Magento Shopping cart price rule for different payment method

Tags: magento

I need to apply the shopping cart price rule following condition.

1. payment method -> credit card = Free shipping.
2. payment method ->
   Cash on delivery = shipping price(100Rs) + Cash on delivery(100Rs)
   when subtotal less than 2000.
3. payment method -> Cash on delivery =
   free shipping + Cash on delivery(100Rs) when subtotal greater than
   2000.

can any one explain above condition for shopping cart price rule or any suitable condition?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for this question  i have similar problem

Answer (score 1):

you can define "Shipping Cart Price Rules". You'll find this under **Promotions -> Shipping Cart Price Rules**

Comment: @justcode here are some useful links: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes feel free to play around with this magento function